# how to improve efficiency of this Python code

Tags: python, csv

I have written a simple code in ABAQUS PDE to export results to csv files. I put a part of it here and I am wondering how I may improve its efficiency.

I am so appreciated for your valuable comments.

```
from odbAccess import *
from abaqusConstants import *

outputname='job-23.odb'

odb=openOdb(outputname)

myAssembly=odb.rootAssembly

% Defining number of elements

nofl=46

s1=open('s1.csv','w')

%Defining lenght of steps
lengthsteps=len(odb.steps.keys())

for j in range(nofl):

    for i in range(lengthsteps-1):
        step=odb.steps.keys()[i]
        s=odb.steps[step]
        jj=odb.steps[opstep].historyRegions.keys()[j]
        sdata=s.historyRegions[jj].historyOutputs['S11'].data
        l=len(sdata)
        for k in range(l-1):
            s1.write('%10.4E\n' % sdata[k][1])


s1.close()
```

Comment: Are you intentionally omitting the last step?

Comment: Before you do anything like porting it into another language, do profiling. E.g using lineprofiler: http://www.huyng.com/posts/python-performance-analysis/

Comment: Maybe this is something for the [CodeReview-Community](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Something which you should **not** use in python is:

```
objectNr = len(myObjects)
for i in range(objectNr-1):
  a = myObjects[i]
  print a
```

Something like this would be better:

```
for myObject in myObjects:
   print myObject
```

In your case would it be maybe easier, when you iter over odb.steps.

```
for step in odb.steps:
  s=odb.steps[step]
  ...
```

Much shorter better to read and it is the python way.

Answer (score 0):

There are some easy ways to improve your code, but I'm not sure exactly how much the performance will change. You were doing some wasteful stuff before, but I don't think it was terribly expensive stuff.

The biggest change is to avoid using `keys()` calls and integer indexes to get the dictionary keys. Instead, we just access the `values()` directly. Since your current code writes out the data interleaved (e.g. grouped by step, rather than by item) we transpose the nested structure we have (lists within a generator expression) with `zip(*(...))`.

```
with open('s1.csv','w') as s1:
    for item in zip(*(step.historyRegions.values() for step in steps.values()[:-1]))
        for step in item:
            for data in step:
                s1.write('%10.4E\n' % data[1])
```